# Issue running node with typescript compilation and Jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I am having an issue using typescript compilation. I'm trying to run this in a docker container but even running locally gives the same errors so I think I am messing up the arguments. I need to run using node.

I am trying to run

```
 node --nolazy -r ./node_modules/tsconfig-paths/register.js -r ./node_modules/ts-node/register ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js
```

which outputs

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'alias' of undefined
    at /home/user/Workspace/project/node_modules/jest-validate/build/validateCLIOptions.js:97:58
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at validateCLIOptions (/home/user/Workspace/project/node_modules/jest-validate/build/validateCLIOptions.js:96:47)
    at buildArgv (/home/user/Workspace/project/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/index.js:192:42)
    at Object.run (/home/user/Workspace/project/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/index.js:155:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/Workspace/project/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/bin/jest.js:16:27)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10
    at Object..js (/home/user/Workspace/project/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1045:43)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
```

If I try and use my Jest config, I get a different error

```
node --nolazy -r ./node_modules/tsconfig-paths/register.js -r ./node_modules/ts-node/register ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --config=./jest-config.json
```

which outputs

```
Usage: jest.js [--config=<pathToConfigFile>] [TestPathPattern]
Options:
   ...[Jest help output]...
(0 , _jestConfig(...).isJSONString) is not a function
```

It seems `tsconfig-paths` is causing the issue since when I remove it the test start to run, but of course they fail because node is expecting javascript and not typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why, but the jest flag `--runInBand` is required. I think from [this blog](https://emmer.dev/blog/debugging-remote-jest-tests/) it might be because otherwise jest spawns child processes?

> `--runInBand` causes all tests to be run in the parent process rather than child processes.

**EDIT:** If anyone is curious, [this is how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67213840/817379) I managed to get remote debugging in Jest tests launched within Docker